# How to clear state immediately after a keyed window is processed?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

My application uses a keyed window that is keyed by a function of timestamp. This means once that particular window has been fired and processed, there is no use in keeping that key active because there is no way that particular key will appear again. Because this use case involves continuously expanding keys, I want to clear the state of a key as soon as it is finished processing without having to configure timers.

Is this something that can be achieved in the `evictor` method or `apply` method after each keyed window is done processing?

Comment: I don't exactly know what you mean. When the watermark exceeds the end of the window, the states will be cleared.

Comment: There are no watermarks. I'm using processing time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows clean up their state automatically. The only case I can think of where you might need to be concerned is if you are using the globalState that hangs off the window context object. But the windows themselves, and their state, are freed as soon as the window has fired (or in the case of event time windows, once the allowed lateness has expired).